# Using VBA to insert title of Access Report

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My database has a global InsertTitle function that will insert a title based on the report name and values used from forms to open the reports. strField is a global variable that is used for the other reports in the report_Open Sub like this

```
strField = ""
If CurrentProject.AllForms("fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport").IsLoaded Then              
If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboSort) And Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboSort <> "ContractID" Then
     strField = Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboSort.Column(1)                                 
 If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboStatus) Then
      strField = strField & "," & Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboStatus.Column(1)
    End If
ElseIf Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboStatus) Then
    strField = "," & Forms!fdlgcontractsummarylookupreport!cboStatus.Column(1)
End If
```

The InsertTitle function is as follows

```
Public Function InsertTitle(strReportName As String) As String

If strReportName = "rptContractSummarized" Then
If strField = "" Then               
    InsertTitle = "Contract Summary Sorted by Contract Number With Active and Inactive Task Orders"
ElseIf Left(strField, 1) = "," Then         
    InsertTitle = "Contract Summary Sorted by Contract Number With " & IIf(Mid(strField, 2, Len(strField) - 1) = "All", "Active and Inactive", Mid(strField, 2, Len(strField) - 1)) & " Task Orders"
ElseIf InStr(1, strField, ",") = 0 Then         
    InsertTitle = "Contract Summary Sorted by " & strField & " With Active and Inactive Task Orders"
Else                                           
    InsertTitle = "Contract Summary Sorted by " & Left(strField, InStr(1, strField, ",") - 1) & " With " & IIf(Mid(strField, InStr(1, strField, ",") + 1, Len(strField) - InStr(1, strField, ",")) = "All", "Active and Inactive", Mid(strField, InStr(1, strField, ",") + 1, Len(strField) - InStr(1, strField, ","))) & " Task Orders"
End If
```

This works perfectly for all reports using this pattern but due to the number of options used to open one of the reports, using strField became to complicated so I am attempting to declare and use other variables to open this report

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strProduct As String
Dim strDelivered As String
Dim strManager As String
Dim strSort As String

If CurrentProject.AllForms("fdlgMasterDeliverables").IsLoaded Then

If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort) Then
     strSort = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort.Column(1)                                  
ElseIf Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived) Then                             
     strDelivered = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived.Column(0) 'strField & "," & Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived.Column(0)    'InStr(1, strField, ",") = 0
End If
If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType) Then
        strProduct = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType.Column(1)
End If
ElseIf Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProjectManager) Then
        strManager = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProjectManager.Column(1)
End If
```

I have changed the pattern a bit for this problem report as follows (with case lists reduced)

```
ElseIf strReportName = "rptMasterDeliverables" Then

Dim strDelivered As String
Dim strProduct As String
Dim strManager As String
Dim strSort As String

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived
    Case "Yes"
        strDelivered = "Received"
    Case "No"
        strDelivered = "Outstanding"
    Case Else
        strDelivered = "All"
End Select

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort
    Case "ContractTO"
        strSort = "Contract Number"
    Case "ContractorName"
        strSort = "Contractor"
    Case Else
        strSort = ""
End Select

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType
    Case 1
        strProduct = "Data Collection/Analysis"
    Case 2
        strProduct = "Data Analysis/Compilation"
    Case 3
        strProduct = "Data Deliverable(Monitoring)"
    Case Else
        strProduct = ""
End Select

If strSort = "" Then
   InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " Deliverables sorted by Project Manager"
ElseIf strSort Like "*" Then
    InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " Deliverables Sorted by " & strSort & ""
ElseIf strProduct Like "*" And strSort Like "*" Then
    InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " " & strProduct & " Deliverables Sorted by " & strSort & ""
Else
    InsertTitle = "deliverables"
End If

End If
```

I have been through so many iterations trying to figure out this problem that I am getting confused. I would appreciate a second (third, forth) eye to advise me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Why to force doors wide open? Have you tried to use custom class (class module)?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not getting any errors and the form is opening correctly. The first two "insertTitles" function correctly. I am having issues with inserting the products

Comment: Whats the value of InsertTitle  after you run the function.. place a debug.print after 

Else
    InsertTitle = "deliverables"
End If

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
ElseIf strProduct Like "*" And strSort Like "*" Then
```

will not be reached because this part is true:

```
ElseIf strSort Like "*" Then
```

when this `strSort Like "*"` is true

So try to re-order the boolean "tests" like this:

```
ElseIf strProduct Like "*" And strSort Like "*" Then
    InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " " & strProduct & " Deliverables Sorted by " & strSort & ""
ElseIf strSort Like "*" Then
    InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " Deliverables Sorted by " & strSort & ""
```

Comment: I like it! I have done the rearrangement unfortunately strProduct still doesn't insert. Is there something in the syntax maybe?

Comment: What's the value of InsertTitle after you run the function.. place a debug.print after Else InsertTitle = "deliverables" End If

Comment: It is always either 
   InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " Deliverables sorted by Project Manager" or
    InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & " Deliverables Sorted by " & strSort & ""
It is like the strProduct doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! Thank you for your assistance.

```
 If strReportName = "rptMasterDeliverables" Then

Dim strDelivered As String
Dim strProduct As String
Dim strManager As String
Dim strSort As String

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived
    Case "Yes"
        strDelivered = "Received"
    Case "No"
        strDelivered = "Outstanding"
    Case Else
        strDelivered = "All"
End Select

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProjectManager
    Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProjectManager.Column(1)
       strManager = " For " & Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProjectManager & ""
    Case Else
        strManager = ""
End Select

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort
    Case "ContractTO"
        strSort = "Contract Number"
    Case "ContractorName"
        strSort = "Contractor"
    Case "ProductType"
        strSort = "Product Type"
    Case "TOBeginDate"
        strSort = "Task Order Start Date"
    Case "TOEndDate"
        strSort = "Task Order End Date"
    Case "Received"
        strSort = "Date Product Received"
    Case Else
        strSort = "Project Manager"
End Select

Select Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType
    Case Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType.Column(1)
        strProduct = " " & Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType & ""
 Case Else
        strProduct = ""
End Select

InsertTitle = "" & strDelivered & strProduct & " Deliverables" & strManager & " Sorted by " & strSort & ""
End IF
```